# Numpy *.npz internal file structure

Tags: python, numpy

can anyone share some info about internal data organization in *.npz ?
Some documentation etc..
Just can't find anything..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

npz is a simple zip archive, which contains numpy files.
Simple review of internal structure of ZIP can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)

Comment: This caught me and I found [this youtube video of Computerphile on Compression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lto-ajuqW3w) it's a rather basic introduction on the matter but enlightening if you're new to the topic.

Answer (score 21):

Here are the docs:

- [Format of .npz files](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html), referring to the
- [Format of .npy files](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/pydoc/numpy.lib.format.html)

That said, I would not recommend trying to read or write files in this format yourself.  It's fine for writing from NumPy and reading in with NumPy again.  But if you want to write or read a file from a different environment, then use a more standard format like HDF5 or NetCDF which is supported by both environments.

Comment: +1: "I would not recommend trying to read or write files in this format yourself".  Agreed.  Use `numpy`.

Comment: OK, try to use NumPy files from C++ or C# without your reader:)

Comment: @taras: You didn't get the point.  Don't try to read .npy files from C or C++.  Use HDF5 instead -- it will save you a lot of work.  If you are not in control of the file generation, write a converter from .npy to HDF5 in Python -- it will probably be less than ten lines of Python code.

Comment: NumPy files are faster to read/write. It is the main point. And they are binary compatible with C/C++ structures, so It is easy to implement C++ reader/writer for .npy/.npz

Comment: @taras: NumPy files are not faster to write than HDF5 (on a Beowulf cluster they might even be slower; and yes, I actually measured this).  And while a .npy reader might be easy to write for some special cases, it is complex in general.  HDF5 will offer much more verstility for free.  If the .npy files are working for you, that's of course fine as well -- I just would have avoided the effort :)

Comment: Some additional information on HDF5 since this was debated here: HDF5 is a data model, library, and file format for storing and managing data. It supports an unlimited variety of datatypes, and is designed for flexible and efficient I/O and for high volume and complex data. HDF5 is portable and is extensible, allowing applications to evolve in their use of HDF5. [- Link to their homepage](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/)