# How to open an .npz file

Tags: python, file

Someone sent me an .npz file. How can I open that file using Python, and read the data from it?

Comment: duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409551/numpy-npz-internal-file-structure ?

Answer (score 53):

use this in python3:

```
from numpy import load

data = load('out.npz')
lst = data.files
for item in lst:
    print(item)
    print(data[item])
```

Comment: This will just print the contents, which you can anyways get by opening the file in any IDE/text editor

Answer (score 33):

You want to use [`numpy.load()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) *with a context manager*:

```
with numpy.load('foo.npz') as data:
    a = data['a']
```

You should use a context manager here, as the documentation states:

> the returned instance of `NpzFile` class must be closed to avoid leaking
>   file descriptors.

and the context manager will handle that for you.

Answer (score 11):

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.load('imdb.npz', allow_pickle=True)
lst = data.files

for item in lst:
    print(item)
    print(data[item])
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) function:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('your_file.npz')
```

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the documentation of np.savez:

> When opening the saved .npz file with load `a NpzFile object` is
> returned. This is a `dictionary-like object` that can be queried for
> its list of arrays (with the `.files attribute`), and for the arrays
> themselves.

You can easily treat it like a dictionary:

```
data = np.load('mat.npz')        # data contains x = [1,2,3,4,5]

for key in data.keys():
    print(key)                        # x
    print(data[key])                  # [1,2,3,4,5]
```

It is a `dictionary-like` object because you cannot assign directly to `data` which is NpzFile object, you will have this error `TypeError: NpzFile' object does not support item assignment`.

But you can convert it to a dictionary and use it completely as dictionary, and save it to .npz file like that:

```
data = dict(data)
data["y"] = np.arange(21)
np.savez("mat",**data)
```