# Loading arrays from numpy npz files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I usually save data in npz files in python. How to write a function which loads the npz file and automatically creates arrays which are present in the `.npz` file. For example, say there are three arrays `A`, `B`, and `C` in a file named `some_data.npz`.

What I want the function to do is load the `npz` file as

```
data1 = np.load('some_data.npz')
```

and then automatically create three arrays named `data1A`, `data1B` and `data1C` which stores the arrays `A`, `B`, and `C` from the original `.npz` file. How to do this?

Comment: Doesn't the `numpy.load` function already give you a dictionary of arrays?  If you just want to bind each individual array to some fancy names, just assign them.  Possibly, write a class and make the three names class attributes.

Comment: @CongMa [exactly](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html). The second example shows how this is accomplished.

Comment: You can read this as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/71183327/16733101

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to create names store the arrays in a `dict`:

```
a1 = np.array([1,2,3])
a2 = np.array([4,5,6])
a3 = np.array([7,8,9])

np.savez("test", A=a1,B=a2,C=a3)
a = np.load("test.npz")
d = dict(zip(("data1A","data1B","data1C"), (a[k] for k in a)))
print(d)
{'data1A': array([4, 5, 6]), 'data1C': array([7, 8, 9]), 'data1B': array([1, 2, 3])}
```

If you want to create the keys without passing the names explicitly:

```
a1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
a2 = np.array([4, 5, 6])
a3 = np.array([7, 8, 9])

np.savez("test", A=a1,B=a2,C=a3)
a = np.load("test.npz")

d = dict(zip(("data1{}".format(k) for k in a), (a[k] for k in a)))
print(d)
```

Comment: Is this not essentially the same as the object returned by `np.load`? Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @areuexperienced, load does not let you pick the name so if you want to store all the arrays with certain names then this is how to do it

Comment: Acknowledged. It's just that one would (or should) usually specify names at savetime, hence making it redundant. Your comment still stands though.

Answer (score 7):

You can almost do that already, via the `f` attribute of the object returned by [`numpy.load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).  For example, in the following, `foo.npz` contains three arrays, `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
In [1367]: foo = np.load('foo.npz')

In [1368]: foo.keys()
Out[1368]: ['A', 'C', 'B']

In [1369]: foo.f.A
Out[1369]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.])

In [1370]: foo.f.B
Out[1370]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [-1,  0]])

In [1371]: foo.f.C
Out[1371]: array([ 3.14159265,  2.71828183,  0.57721566])
```

*Note*: The `f` attribute is not documented in the docstring of `load`.  When `load` reads an `npz` file, it returns an instance of the class `NpzFile`.  This class is available as `numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile`.  The docstring of the `NpzFile` class describes the `f` attribute.  (As of this writing, the source code of the class can be found here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L95.)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Assuming that you saved the original data with labels 'A', 'B', and 'C'
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([1,2,3])
a2 = np.array([4,5,6])
a3 = np.array([7,8,9])
# Save the arrays:
np.savez_compressed('some_data.npz', A=a1,B=a2,C=a3)

# Now Load Using,
data1 = np.load('some_data.npz', 'r')
data1A = data1['A']
data1B = data1['B']
data1C = data1['C']
```

Hope this helps !!