# Reading a zipped NumPy file during "with open() as f"

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a data generator in Python, based on the "fit_generator" function at https://keras.io/models/sequential/. The code for the function is:

```
def generate_arrays_from_file():
    while True:
        with open('data.npz') as f:
            for line in f:
                # TODO
                yield ({'input': x}, {'output': y})
```

In the line `TODO`, I need to assign some data from `f` to `x` and `y`.

Now, the file 'data.npz' is actually a zipped NumPy file. This was created by:

```
x = random_numpy_array()  # Create a NumPy array (details not important)
y = random_numpy_array()
np.savez('data.npz', x=x, y=y)
```

Usually, you would read `x` and `y` by using:

```
data = np.load('data.npz')
x = data['x']
y = data['y']
```

However, in my example (the first block of code above), I have not loaded the data using `np.load()`. Instead, I have loaded it using `with open('data.npz') as f`.

To read `x` and `y` from `f`, I have tried:

```
x = f['x']
y = f['y']
```

But this gives me the error:

```
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

So how can I read `f` and extract `x` and `y`?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you cannot read with `np.load()`? Also, `f` is only the _file handler_, not the _data_. You would have to use something like `data = f.readlines()`, but due to the compressed nature of the npz file that will also only result in gibberish.

Comment: What is the purpose of while when you are already iterating through the file with for loop ?

Comment: A .npy cannot be read `by line`.  It isn't a text file.  A `npz` is a archive of npy.  It makes even less sense to try `by line` of an archive,

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to use the load function for numpy files. It'll load it into an array with which you can then store the arrays in a dictionary if thats what you want.

see [Loading arrays from npz files in pythhon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682928/loading-arrays-from-npz-files-in-pythhon?rq=1)