# Open and view .npz file in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an unknown .npz file and would like to see whats inside. I am very new to Python.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> b = numpy.load('data.npz')
>>> print(b.files)
['arr_1', 'arr_0', 'arr_3', 'arr_2']
```

How do I see what these `arr_i` contain (i.e. dimension, values, etc.)?

Comment: `b['arr_1']` I think anyway

Comment: Yep, that did it! Kind of feel silly asking.

Comment: There are examples of saving and loading at the bottom of the NumPy docs for [`numpy.savez_compressed()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html) and  [`numpy.load()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).

Comment: You can read more on this link to now the internal structure of npz file https://stackoverflow.com/a/71183327/16733101

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
np.savez_compressed('filename.npz', array1=array1, array2=array2)
b = np.load('filename.npz')
```

And do b['array_1'], b['array_2'] and so on to retrieve data from each array.

Comment: As an additional note, if we use `with open(filename, 'rb') as f:     b=np.load(f)`    , it gives error. So,  we should just simply use np.load(filename)  :)

Answer (score 16):

Python provides "npzviewer" to open .npz files

> pip install npzviewer
>
> npzviewer [-h] [-v] [npzfile]

https://pypi.org/project/npzviewer/