# How could I split test and train npzfiles data?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I convert my .txt data to npzfile now I want split it to test and train for train Generator in GAN but I don't know how define x and then use:

```
x_train, x_test  = train_test_split(x, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

Note: my data doesn't have a label.

My data is:

```
df= np.load("D:\\Code\\data.npz") 
print(df) 
out:<numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x000000000EF0BFD0>
```

Comment: my data is df= np.load("D:\\Code\\data.npz")
print(df)   out:<numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x000000000EF0BFD0>

Comment: What are the contents of the npz? Is it just one file? (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51465553/1240268)