# Attaching additional variables to npz file

Tags: python, numpy

I essentially want to append an extra variable to a bunch of npz files, however I know I can't do this directly, so what I want to do is load each npz file one at a time, and save it to a new npz file with the addition of adding one more variable to this file.

Now the problem is that my npz files have dynamic number of variables and I need to preserve the names of these variables as well.

Example:

```
d = np.load(file_in)
d.files
>>['seq', 'pssm', 'entropy', 'rCa', 'rCb', 'rN', 'id', 'log_units', 'AA_LIST']
```

Now I wish to save a new npz file that saves all these variables with the same keyword, and one additional variable saved as : 'new_key'

Comment: A `npz` is `zip` archive.  Look at it with OS zip or archive tools.

Comment: You can embed all your data as one dictionary and write it to one .npz file like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71183327/16733101